# how to fix object creating a duplicate of itself during animation?

Tags: animation, armature

so, i've worked on making an animation for a game i'm making. however, when i move the player in the animation (for my diving animation) the player's eyes make a static duplicate of themself and the first pair stays on the head, while the second pair creates a kind of *"bunny ears"* for the player. i've wen't in edit mode and checked if there was a second layer of eyes somehow inside of it, but there wasn't. i attached a screenshot and really would appreciate it if someone showed me how to get rid of them. thank you[image]

Comment: Yes you must have duplicated your eyes, maybe go in Edit mode, select all and Merge by Distance?

Comment: @moonboots what value?

Comment: Select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance

Comment: @moonboots yea, which value do i set the "distance" number to or leave it as default bc default doesnt fix anything

Comment: the value is the merge threshold, maybe increase to see if it gives something, if it doesn't fix your problem could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots how do i share it with u

Comment: use https://blend-exchange.com/ (read the instructions) or use a platform like workupload and share the file

Comment: @moonboots would mega work? here https://mega.nz/file/cTcXQBgb#bL-42WC3nD400gbpC3EEO5-3PUeLzVRB0jJN53Mn-J4

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much! last thing, how do i get the eyes back in the right spot? they are above the head still now. (before that one of the pairs stayed correctly on the face but these don't) oh and couldnt find how to fix upside down character so yea

Comment: I've edited my answer to add some precisions, I hope it helps

Comment: @moonboots thank you so much! u are amazing <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a duplication of your eye mesh on the other side of your mirror axis, select it with <kbd>L</kbd> and delete (by the way your character is upside down):

[image]

Now assign the remaining eyes to the good vertex group:

[image]

To bring back the armature to its default rotation, rotate it 180° on Y and apply the rotation and scale (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>). To bring back the armature to its rest pose, switch to *Pose* mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>. Also put the *Subdivision Surface* modifier at the bottom of the modifiers stack, and enable the *Preserve Volume* option of the *Armature* modifier.